# Add external UI component to Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wanna add an external UI component to storyboard in Xcode 6 (for instance, a custom button from https://github.com/a1anyip/AYVibrantButton). Is it possible to add it to storyboard directly by drag and drop? If not, where shall I call the init function and how do I specify its position in the code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code, and the ReadMe for the `AYVibrantButton`, it says that you should add the button to a `UIVisualEffectView`, and that it must be instantiated with `initWithFrame:style:`. When you add a button to the storyboard and set its class to `AYVibrantButton`, the init method called will be `initWithCoder:`, so none of the setup that the author does in `initWithFrame:style:` takes place. If you want to add the button in the storyboard, you need to update the code to include an `initWithCoder:` method. Replace the `initWithFrame:style:` implementation in the Author's code with the following,

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(AYVibrantButtonStyle)style {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.style = style;
        [self commonSetup];
    }
    return self;
}


-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.style = AYVibrantButtonStyleFill; // need to add add a style here. Change it to one of the other styles to match your needs
        [self commonSetup];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)commonSetup {
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    // default values
    _animated = YES;
    _animationDuration = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultAnimationDuration;
    _cornerRadius = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultCornerRadius;
    _roundingCorners = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultRoundingCorners;
    _borderWidth = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultBorderWidth;
    _translucencyAlphaNormal = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultTranslucencyAlphaNormal;
    _translucencyAlphaHighlighted = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultTranslucencyAlphaHighlighted;
    _alpha = kAYVibrantButtonDefaultAlpha;
    _activeTouch = NO;

    // create overlay views
    [self createOverlays];

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    // add the default vibrancy effect
    self.vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];
#endif

    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown | UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside | UIControlEventTouchCancel];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So shall I add the code in ViewController.m?

Comment: @Xin No, the code goes in AYVibrantButton.m. As I said in my answer, you need to replace the authors implementation of initWithFrame:style: with the code I posted.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now the button showed up after using your code but I don't know why the button title is missing... so there's only an empty button

Comment: @Xin I noticed that too. You need to add the title in code.

Comment: is that the way how to work with all external UI components or just an design deficiency?

Comment: @Xin I think this is a design deficiency. The author has a method of his own for setting the title called `setText:`. The usual method, `setTitle:forState:` doesn't work, which is why setting the title in IB fails. Personally, I don't think this is a very good custom button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77219/discussion-between-james-and-rdelmar).

Answer (score 1):

The object is a subclass of UIButton. So assuming that the .h/.m files are in your project, just add a UIButton to storyboard, go to the identity inspector, and change the class from UIButton to AYVibrantButton. If you need to do anything special with it, just create an outlet to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh. I added a button and changed its class to AYVibrantButton in identity inspector but it didn't show up when running the program. Is there anything else to set up for it to show up?

Comment: You need to add constraints so it knows how to place it on the screen

Comment: Thanks Josh but could you be more specific. I don't know where to add constraints.

Comment: In storyboard, you use control drag to add layout contraints.  There are too many to mention here, so I would read up on it.